# MainActivity.java does not recognize id's from different xml file than main_page.xml

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, crash

I have the following code in MainActivity.java onCreate method:

```
        googleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        volume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
```

The sign_in_button and seekBar ids are located in settings.xml instead of main_page.xml and these lines give me an error: "@layout/main_page does not contain a declaration with id .."

Im working on Android studio

I tried using built solutions in IDE and all of them are causing my app crash

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are setting wrong XML file in *setContentView()* method.

If it contains

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_page)
```

Change it to

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings)
```

Also please share more details i.e. Full error logs, full code of the activity class and also XML layout files. It will be easier to identify the problem.

Comment: I mean full code is large, but that specific thing makes my app crash, also yeah - indeed i have the setContentView(R.layout.main_page) in onCreate function because i am using stuff from main xml file as well, is there any way to access to ids located in 2 different xml files?

Comment: Ohh, no you can't do that, it's not allowed. Since each activity has it's own layout and it can only access it's own layout elements. It cannot touch or access the views of other activities.